# download xcode15beta and build errror

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, libiconv

I downloaded xcode15 beta, and then run the project and reported an error, but I did not report an error when I ran it with xcode14.3.

the error info is：

> Library 'iconv.2.4.0' not found
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] for tips how to write a good question. You can [edit] your question with additional information. This will help others answering your question.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I seemed to be linking against an older version of libiconv that was no longer available.

I was able to fix this by going into **Build Phases** > **Link Binary With Libraries**, removing the old versions of libiconv (in my case I was seeing `libiconv.2.4.0.tbd` and `libiconv.2.4.0.dylib`), and adding `libiconv.tbd` back using the `+` button.

Answer (score 0):

Search for '**iconv.2.4.0**' globally and replace it with '**iconv.2**' , then I compiled successfully. Because I did not search for 'iconv.2.4.0' in xcode 15 beta 3, it should be renamed to 'iconv.2'.