# Error (Xcode): Library 'iconv.2.4.0' not found

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm running a Flutter project. I updated my Xcode to Version 15.0.1 (15A507) and started encountering the error below. I've tried various solutions on the internet, but haven't had any positive results. I found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76455043/download-xcode15beta-and-build-errror), and these two libraries (libiconv.2.4.0.tbd and libiconv.2.4.0.dylib) are indeed removed from the project. However, it's not working the same way. Does anyone know what might be the issue?

> Launching lib/main_dev.dart on iPad de lucas (2) in debug mode...
> main_dev.dart:1
> Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
> Upgrading project.pbxproj
> Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
> Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: HLT4NS3S64
> Xcode build done.                                           54,3s
> Failed to build iOS app
> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
> Error (Xcode): Library 'iconv.2.4.0' not found
> Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> Error launching application on iPad de lucas (2).
> Exited (1)

Note: I couldn't determine if iconv.2.4.0 is used in any library of my project, and the conflict might be arising from that. I've searched to see if it belongs to any library, but couldn't find it.